# How to apply corner radius for UISearchBar background view in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I want to apply a corner radius for the background view of the UISearchBar(the gray part) like the image below.I know applying corner radius to the text field, but how to apply for the background gray part? Is it possible to do so?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005980/how-to-change-uisearchbar-from-round-to-rectangle

Comment: One think you can set background image or else Create view with with gray background and add search bar as sub view. For your view set boarder.

Answer (score -1):

You can make image like above(searchbar_Img.png) and set to search bar as below.. (OR) you can make rounded rect to your text field

```
     UITextField *txfSearchField = [yoursearchbarref valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
    [txfSearchField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [txfSearchField setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeNever];
    [txfSearchField setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeNever];
    [txfSearchField setBackground:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchbar_Img.png"]];

    [txfSearchField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
    //txfSearchField.layer.borderWidth = 8.0f;
    //txfSearchField.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    txfSearchField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    txfSearchField.clearButtonMode=UITextFieldViewModeNever;
```

(OR)

```
for (UIView *searchBarSubview in [searchbar subviews])
    {
        if ([searchBarSubview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)])
        {
            @try
            {
                [(UITextField *)searchBarSubview setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];

            }
            @catch (NSException * e)
            {
                // ignore exception
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps you..